# golang cannot find existing table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to learn databases in golang with postgresql by tutorials.

Although database exists, program gives  output:

```
go run dbase.go

2017/01/02 20:43:07 pq: database "bookstore" does not exist
```

this is psql output:

```
deneme=# \l
                             List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate | Ctype |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+---------+-------+-----------------------
 bookstore | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     | 
 deneme    | postgres | UTF8     | C       | C     |
```

and this is the relevant part of go code:

```
const (
    DB_USER     = "postgres"
    DB_PASSWORD = "root"
    DB_NAME     = "bookstore"
)

func main() {
    dbinfo := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable",
        DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", dbinfo)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Also changing connection code to this gives the same output:

```
db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "postgres://postgres:root@localhost/bookstore?sslmode=disable")
```

Thanks;

Comment: Are you running localhost ?

Comment: database and go are running on the same laptop, if you are asking this. If "running localhost" is a configuration term about postgres, no, i didn't adjust anything. Just installed postgresql.

Comment: check to see that you don't have more than one pg installed

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem.